# Spring birt integration example maven error

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, birt

I've found a good example of how to integrate maven into spring mvc which is what I would like to do.

https://github.com/joshlong/spring-birt

I've downloaded the project and imported the maven project into Spring STS. I can do a maven install on the spring-birt-integration project which produces a spring-birt-integration.jar however when I do a maven install on spring-birt-integration-example I get an error....

```
Failed to execute goal on project spring-birt-integration-example: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project org.eclipse.birt.spring:spring-birt-integration-example:war:1.0: 
    Failed to collect dependencies for [org.eclipse.birt.spring:spring-birt-integration:jar:1.0 (compile), org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE (compile), org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:jar:3.0.20100224 (compile), cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2 (compile), javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1 (compile), mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.9 (compile)]: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.eclipse.birt.spring:spring-birt-integration:jar:1.0: Failure to find org.eclipse.birt.spring:spring-birt:pom:1.0 in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of sonatype-nexus-releases has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

The setup in the pom file looks as if the example inherits dependencies from the spring-birt-integration project. This is the first time I've seen this and I'm a bit unsure how to fix.

Can anyone give me some advice please.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a silly question. After reading my errors more I realized that I had forgotten to import the top level pom file. There are actually three for this project.

This is the first time I've seen a maven project laid out with two pom.xml files which inherit from parent projects. Very interesting.